# How to extract meta data out of a URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Let's say I am saving a bit.ly url. How do I extract metadata out of it? As in, which site does it belong to(I can always expand the url by doing a Request) but I want more from the url. Like its image or any sort of meta-data that can be associated with the original url.

Example:
For a youtube link, how does one extract the favicon image of youtube and the image(frame) that youtube shows when you load a youtube url. Do I've to use the youtube api here or can I extract that info from the data?

I hope I am not being vague here.

Answer (score 1):

Shortened urls typically act as an index rather than an encoding of the underlying data. That is you contact the url shortening site with the value in the url and it does a look up to find the associated url.  It doesn't *decode* it, but uses the value as an index into a set of stored urls. You'd have to use an API if there is one available to discover more information or, as you've noted, actually do the request and get the data from the response.

Comment: Seems like a bit of pain, isn't it? If someone encodes a youtube url with a bit.ly url, I've the use of api of bitly first, get the url, then use youtube api to get any data. Any better way?

Comment: @Puck The trouble you're having is a perfect reason why people use this service...not just shortening URLs.

Comment: So how does something like Pocket manages to get the meta-data out of a url?